# Blue border rendering on drop down select [chrome]

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, html-select, shadow-dom

I have the task to track down and remove this blue border around the drop down box however I have not seen any css that is relevant to this. From what I've read the drop down is part of the shadow dom but where is this blue border coming from?

[image: blue border]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where it's coming from, but you can override it by using CSS if you have the privilege to update the css.
I don't know how your markup is like, but this will override the blue border.

```
.class-dropdown {
  outline: none;
}
```

**NOTE:** If accessibility is a requirement, it's probably bad idea to remove the blue border. What is better probably have a state style when the dropdown showing / selected

Hope this helps.

Comment: you can directly apply the rule to the select element: `select { outline: none }`